# Metabox Not Showing on Custom Post Type But On Pages and Post

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, metabox

I have a Custom Post Type like

```
function cpt_Projects() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                 => 'Projects',
        'singular_name'        => 'Project',
        'menu_name'            => 'Projects',
        'name_admin_bar'       => 'Projects',
        'parent_item_colon'    => 'Parent Projects:',
        'all_items'            => 'All Projects',
        'view_item'            => 'View Project',
        'add_new_item'         => 'Add New Project',
        'add_new'              => 'Add New Project',
        'new_item'             => 'New Projects',
        'edit_item'            => 'Edit Project Item',
        'update_item'          => 'Update Project Item',
        'search_items'         => 'Search Project Item',
        'not_found'            => 'Project Not found',
        'not_found_in_trash'   => 'Project Not found in Trash',
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                => 'ProjectsCPT',
        'description'          => 'This Post Type Adds Eyeglasses to Website',
        'labels'               => $labels,
        'supports'             => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
        'taxonomies'           => array( 'ProjectsTax' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_details_metabox',
        'hierarchical'         => true,
        'public'               => true,
        'show_ui'              => true,
        'show_in_menu'         => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'    => true,
        'menu_position'        => 5,
        'can_export'           => true,
        'has_archive'          => true,
        'exclude_from_search'  => false,
        'publicly_queryable'   => true,
        'capability_type'      => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'ProjectsCPT', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'cpt_Projects', 0 );
```

and a Metabox like

```
  function add_details_metabox($post_type) {
    $types = array('post', 'page', 'ProjectsCPT');

   if (in_array($post_type, $types)) {
      add_meta_box(
        'details-metabox',
        'Project Details',
        'detail_meta_callback',
        $post_type,
        'normal',
        'high'
      );
   }
  }
```

after running the code the Metabox is showing on all `Page`s and `Post`s but not on Custom Post Type `ProjectsCPT` Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? (It works fine if I remove the if statement

```
 if (in_array($post_type, $types)) {}
```

but this add metabox to all Posts and Pages which is not what I need to do

Answer (score 2):

Post type names cannot contain capital letters. So behind the scenes, your CPT is probably called projectscpt rather than ProjectsCPT - hence it not matching the value in your array.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE the difference between [`add_meta_boxes`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes) and `register_meta_box_cb`.

When you register the meta boxes using `add_meta_boxes`, here is how WordPress calls `do_action()`

```
/**
 * Fires after all built-in meta boxes have been added.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string  $post_type Post type.
 * @param WP_Post $post      Post object.
 */
do_action( 'add_meta_boxes', $post_type, $post );
```

The first argument is post type and the second one is post object.

And when callback is registered using `register_meta_box_cb` then in `register_post_type()` function WordPress add an action.

```
if ( $args->register_meta_box_cb )
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_' . $post_type, $args->register_meta_box_cb, 10, 1 );
```

Then

```
/**
 * Fires after all built-in meta boxes have been added, contextually for the given post type.
 *
 * The dynamic portion of the hook, `$post_type`, refers to the post type of the post.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param WP_Post $post Post object.
 */
do_action( 'add_meta_boxes_' . $post_type, $post );
```

So the first and only argument is `$post` the post object and you are using it as post type.

You have to get the post type before comparing.

Example:-

```
function add_details_metabox($post) {
    $types = array('post', 'page', 'projectscpt');
    $post_type = get_post_type($post);

    if (in_array($post_type, $types)) {
        add_meta_box(
            'details-metabox',
            'Project Details',
            'detail_meta_callback',
            $post_type,
            'normal',
            'high'
        );
    }
}
```

**NOTE #1** As @vancoder answered, no matter what case you pass in post type. It is converted to lowercase. What WordPress recommends to register post type without spaces and capital letters. You must use `projectscpt` instead of capital letters.

**NOTE #2** When using `register_meta_box_cb` it hook the callback function on `add_meta_boxes_{post_type}` action. This meta box will not appear on any other post type. Therefore, you do not need to check the post type in callback function. If you are getting meta box on other post types too then check the code, perhaps you made some mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add your custom post type in the add_meta_box function arguments for $screen.

add_meta_box( string $id, string $title, callable $callback, **`string|array|WP_Screen $screen = null,`** string $context = 'advanced', string $priority = 'default', array $callback_args = null )

**Example:**

```
add_meta_box( 
    'my_id', My Title, 'my_callback_function', '**my_post_type**', 'normal', 'default' 
);
```